# Tensorflow / Keras, trouble with Embedding and sparse_categorical_crossentropy

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Keras noob here,

I'm trying to build an LSTM network to generate text using Shakespeare's works. (A bit like in [this](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/colab/shakespeare_with_tpu_and_keras.ipynb) tutorial)

This the method which generates my model:

```
def generate_model(seq_len=100, stateful=True):
    # Initialize model
    source = tf.keras.Input(
        name='seed', shape=(seq_len,), dtype=tf.int32)

    # Embed ascii character (0 to 255) into one hot encoding (0, 1, 0...)
    embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=256, output_dim=EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=seq_len)(source)

    # Good old LSTM's
    lstm_1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(EMBEDDING_DIM, stateful=stateful, return_sequences=True)(embedding)
    lstm_2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(EMBEDDING_DIM, stateful=stateful, return_sequences=True)(lstm_1)

    # I honestly don't understand what the TimeDistributed method does
    predicted_char = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='softmax'))(lstm_2)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[source], outputs=[predicted_char])

    model.compile(
        optimizer=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01),
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
    return model
```

I thought the Embedding layer was responsible for one-hot encoding all my characters into vectors. If this is true, is that structure not preserved while passing through the LSTM layers? I'm a bit confused.

For reference, this is an example of an input:
`[65 76 76 83 32 87 69 76 76 32]`

(before encoding it would be)
`['A', 'L', 'L', 'S', ' ', 'W', 'E', 'L', 'L', ' ']`

The corresponding label is the next character in the sequence:
`[84]` ie `['T']`

I'm struggling with what appears to be a common error among newcomers

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [100,256] and labels shape [1]
     [[{{node loss/time_distributed_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]]
     [[{{node training/TFOptimizer/gradients/embedding/embedding_lookup_grad/Reshape}}]]
```

From the research I've done, it would appear that this has to do with my use of *sparse_categorical_crossentropy*, however, if I use *categorical_crossentropy* I get the following error during training

```
ValueError: You are passing a target array of shape (5524624, 1) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. `categorical_crossentropy` expects targets to be binary matrices (1s and 0s) of shape (samples, classes). If your targets are integer classes, you can convert them to the expected format via:
```

I must be missing something, how could I get my model to train?

Thank you, I would really appreciate any help :))

Edit:
If it could be useful, this is all of my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


SHAKESPEARE_TXT = 'shakespeare.txt'

with open(SHAKESPEARE_TXT, 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
    raw = f.read()


def encode(txt):
    # drop any non-ascii characters
    output = np.asarray([ord(c) for c in txt if ord(c) < 255 and c != '\r'], dtype=np.int32)

    return output

def decode(txt):
    return [chr(c) for c in txt]

def get_training_data(seq_len, txt=raw):
    source = encode(txt)

    x, y = [], []

    n = len(source) - seq_len
    #n=100

    for i in range(n):
        sequence = source[i: i + seq_len]

        x.append(sequence)

        y.append([source[i + seq_len]])

    return np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y)





# txt = encode(raw)
# print(decode(txt[0:100]))
'''
training_data = get_training_data(seq_len=10)

for i in range(10):
    print(decode(training_data[0][i]), decode(training_data[1][i]))
'''


EMBEDDING_DIM = 512

def generate_model(seq_len=100, stateful=True):
    # Initialize model
    source = tf.keras.Input(
        name='seed', shape=(seq_len,), dtype=tf.int32)

    # Embed ascii character (0 to 255) into one hot encoding (0, 1, 0...)
    embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=256, output_dim=EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=seq_len)(source)

    # Good old LSTM's
    lstm_1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(EMBEDDING_DIM, stateful=stateful, return_sequences=True)(embedding)
    lstm_2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(EMBEDDING_DIM, stateful=stateful, return_sequences=True)(lstm_1)

    # I honestly don't understand what the TimeDistributed method does
    predicted_char = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='softmax'))(lstm_2)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[source], outputs=[predicted_char])

    model.compile(
        optimizer=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01),
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
    return model


def train():
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

    print("Creating model")

    training_model = generate_model(seq_len=100, stateful=False)

    '''
    tpu_model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(
        training_model,
        strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(
            tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_WORKER)))
    '''

    print("Training")

    data = get_training_data(seq_len=100)
    '''
    print(data[0].shape)
    print(data[0][0])
    print(data[1].shape)
    print(data[1][0])
    '''

    # Start training
    training_model.fit(
        x=data[0],
        y=data[1],
        batch_size=1,
        # steps_per_epoch=100,
        epochs=2
    )

    print("Saving")

    training_model.save_weights('/tmp/bard.h5', overwrite=True)


train()
```

Comment: I think, The error you get when you are using ```categorical_crossentropy``` expected a one-hot code to the labels if the class 0-9 and the label is 6 the label should be [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0].

Comment: That because of the probability for 6 is one in this label and the other 0. that related to the ```softmax``` activation function you are using in the last layer